# SMTP error Wordpress 4.9.1

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, phpmailer

I have 2 website Wordpress.

One site uses Wordpress 4.8.3, and it can send mail by SMTP.

The other site uses Wordpress 4.9.1 and gives an SMTP error that it can't send mail by STMP.

I am using the WP SMTP plugin.

Comment: you can try to contact with your hosting support due it may be the server side problem

Comment: I run site on localhost not hosting :(

Comment: you can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure C:\xampp\php\php.ini and c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini for gmail to send mail.

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

Comment: Amazing. 2 site can't send mail on localhost but they can send mail on hosting online. I don't know how about it. 2 days ago they were still working normally

Answer (score 0):

Here is wordpress SMTP plugin for sending emails without local smtp server https://wordpress.org/plugins/blastex 
You can send from **wp_mail()** function with html (minimal Php version 5.1):

```
< ?php
$to = 'hello@emal.com, hello@boom.com';
$subject 'Hello from email client';
$html = '<h1>Hello message from smtp! </h1> Message from wordpress plugin!';

// Install and activate plugin and send emails (1 - sent, 0- error)
$ok = wp_mail($to, $subject, $html);

// Show error
echo get_option('blastex_error');
?>
```

Plugin gets mx hostname for sending email from dns servers.
You can try!